# Windows Kernel Driver: How to determine if thread terminated?

Tags: c, windows, multithreading, driver, windows-kernel

I have a thread that to some operations and it needs to be alive until a flag says otherwise.

I use [PsCreateSystemThread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/wdm/nf-wdm-pscreatesystemthread) to create the thread and then use [ObReferenceObjectByHandle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/wdm/nf-wdm-obreferenceobjectbyhandle) to get [ETHREAD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/kernel/eprocess) object reference to waiting for the thread to terminate before the driver unloaded using [KeWaitForSingleObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/wdm/nf-wdm-kewaitforsingleobject).

> The function that creates the thread and retrieves a reference to it:

```
ntStatus = PsCreateSystemThread(
    &hThread,
    (ACCESS_MASK)0, NULL,
    (HANDLE)0, NULL,
    ThreadRoutine,
    (PVOID)pThreadData
);
if (!NT_SUCCESS(ntStatus))
{
    return ntStatus;
}

ntStatus = ObReferenceObjectByHandle(
    hThread,
    THREAD_ALL_ACCESS,
    NULL,
    KernelMode,
    (PVOID*)&ptThreadObject,
    NULL
);
if (!NT_SUCCESS(ntStatus))
{
    bStopThread = TRUE;
    ptThreadObject = NULL;
    return ntStatus;
}
```

> The thread routine:

```
LARGE_INTEGER liSleepTime;
while (FALSE == bThread)
{
    liSleepTime.QuadPart = 1000 * RELATIVE_MILLISECOND;
    KeDelayExecutionThread(KernelMode, FALSE, (&liSleepTime));

    ExAcquireFastMutex(&fmMutex);
    //DO SOMTHING
    ExReleaseFastMutex(&fmMutex);
}

PsTerminateSystemThread(STATUS_SUCCESS);
```

> The unload driver function:

```
if (NULL != ptThreadObject)
{
    bStopThread = TRUE;

    KeWaitForSingleObject(
        (PVOID)ptThreadObject,
        Executive,
        KernelMode,
        FALSE,
        (&liTimeOut));
    ObDereferenceObject((PVOID)ptThreadObject);
    ptThreadObject= NULL;
}
```

I need this thread to run all the time.

**Is there a way to check if the thread is terminated prematurely?** (If it was done by [PsTerminateSystemThread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/wdm/nf-wdm-psterminatesystemthread) I can add a 'boolean' and set it before calling PsTerminateSystemThread to terminate the thread).

> One more question:

I terminated the thread at the start of its routine and waited for 20 seconds before calling ObReferenceObjectByHandle and it didn't fail.

```
ntStatus = PsCreateSystemThread(
    &hThread,
    (ACCESS_MASK)0, NULL,
    (HANDLE)0, NULL,
    ThreadRoutine,
    (PVOID)pThreadData
);
if (!NT_SUCCESS(ntStatus))
{
    return ntStatus;
}
// The ThreadRoutine calling PsTerminateSystemThread first and terminate.

liSleepTime.QuadPart = 20000 * RELATIVE_MILLISECOND;
KeDelayExecutionThread(KernelMode, FALSE, (&liSleepTime));

ntStatus = ObReferenceObjectByHandle(
    hThread,
    THREAD_ALL_ACCESS,
    NULL,
    KernelMode,
    (PVOID*)&ptThreadObject,
    NULL
);
if (!NT_SUCCESS(ntStatus))
{
    bStopThread = TRUE;
    ptThreadObject = NULL;
    return ntStatus;
}
```

**Why does ObReferenceObjectByHandle succeed and not fail?** -The thread is long gone.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why does [`ObReferenceObjectByHandle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/wdm/nf-wdm-obreferenceobjectbyhandle) succeed and not fail? -The thread
>   is long gone.

but why it must fail ?? [`ObReferenceObjectByHandle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/wdm/nf-wdm-obreferenceobjectbyhandle) simply return returns the corresponding pointer to the object's body. `ETHREAD` in your case. the state of object - not play any role here. terminated thread or not absolute unrelated. until you have handles or referenced pointers to thread body structure (`ETHREAD`) - the object will be not freed. so, if `hThread` is valid handle - `ObReferenceObjectByHandle` must succeed.

> How to determine if thread terminated?

very easy - simply wait on it say via `KeWaitForSingleObject`, which you already done. because thread objects are themselves a type of dispatcher object, when thread terminated, it set to signal state and `KeWaitForSingleObject` return.

```
if (ptThreadObject)
{
    bStopThread = TRUE;

    KeWaitForSingleObject(
        ptThreadObject,
        Executive,
        KernelMode,
        FALSE,
        0);
    ObDereferenceObject(ptThreadObject);
}
```

note - you must set *Timeout* to 0 for waits indefinitely until the thread terminated (dispatcher object is set to the signaled state). also you not need cast `ptThreadObject` to `PVOID` - it is already pointer. `(PVOID)ptThreadObject` is not error, but superfluous and unnecessary code.

> Is there a way to check if the thread is terminated **prematurely**?

the operation system and i not understand what you mean under **prematurely**. check that thread terminated we can via wait on it. but prematurely can have sense only in context of your code. say you can set different thread exit status via `PsTerminateSystemThread` and than (after thread terminated) get this exist status via `PsGetThreadExitStatus` . if thread still running the `PsGetThreadExitStatus` return `STATUS_PENDING`. this routine can be partially used to check thread state too - if it return any status different from `STATUS_PENDING` - thread is terminated. but if it return `STATUS_PENDING` - unclear - or thread still running, or thread exist via `PsTerminateSystemThread(STATUS_PENDING)`. of course use `STATUS_PENDING` as exist status is bad idea and never must be used. under this condition you can determine thread state (running/terminated) with `PsGetThreadExitStatus` too, but this routine not wait. but your driver logic require **wait** when thread terminated, and only after this we can unload driver. so only `KeWaitForSingleObject` (or another wait function) is correct solution here. if thread can exist in different ways - use different exit status in call `PsTerminateSystemThread` and get it back via `PsGetThreadExitStatus` after thread terminated (so after `KeWaitForSingleObject`)

however call to `PsTerminateSystemThread` is optional - you can simply return from `ThreadRoutine` - in this case system yourself call `PsTerminateSystemThread(STATUS_SUCCESS);` - so in your code call `PsTerminateSystemThread(STATUS_SUCCESS);` also superfluous and unnecessary code. you need call `PsTerminateSystemThread` only in case you want return status different from `STATUS_SUCCESS` and **check** return status after thread terminated. note that windows itself not interpret and use thread exit status. it simply store it in `ETHREAD` object. if you not query and use this status - does not matter what its exit status.

also `liSleepTime.QuadPart = 1000 * RELATIVE_MILLISECOND;` line you can out from loop - set before loop, if you use **constant** timeout.

also we can not wait for thread termination in driver unload at all, if use special thread entry point in asm code. obviously that driver must not be unloaded, until thread is running. for this exist 2 solution - one is wait in driver unload routine, for all drivers thread termination. but exist and another - add reference to driver object, when we create thread, and de-reference driver object, when thread exit.

so define global variable:

```
PDRIVER_OBJECT gDriverObject;
```

in `DriverEntry` initialize it: `gDriverObject = DriverObject;`

and start thread in next way:

```
ObfReferenceObject(gDriverObject);

NTSTATUS status = PsCreateSystemThread(
    &hThread,
    0, NULL,
    0, NULL,
    ThreadRoutine,
    pThreadData
    );
if (!NT_SUCCESS(status))
{
    ObfDereferenceObject(gDriverObject);
}
```

and on thread exit need call `ObfDereferenceObject(gDriverObject);`. but after `ObfDereferenceObject(gDriverObject);` we already can not return to driver code - it can be already unloaded. so this call can not be done from *c/c++* code. in user mode exist [`FreeLibraryAndExitThread`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683153(v=vs.85).aspx), but in kernel mode no analog of this api. only solution - implement thread entry point in asm code - this entry call *c/c++* thread routine and finally **jmp** (but not **call**) to `ObfDereferenceObject`.

define your *c/c++* proc as

```
void NTAPI _ThreadRoutine(PVOID pv)
{
// not call PsTerminateSystemThread here !!
}
```

code for *x64* and *c* (`ml64 /c /Cp $(InputFileName) -> $(InputName).obj`)

```
extern _ThreadRoutine : PROC
extern gDriverObject : QWORD
extern __imp_ObfDereferenceObject : QWORD

_TEXT segment 'CODE'

ThreadRoutine proc
    sub rsp,28h
    call _ThreadRoutine
    add rsp,28h
    mov rcx,gDriverObject
    jmp __imp_ObfDereferenceObject
ThreadRoutine endp

_TEXT ENDS

end
```

code for *x86* and *c* (`ml /c /Cp $(InputFileName) -> $(InputName).obj`)

```
.686

extern _gDriverObject:DWORD
extern __imp_@ObfDereferenceObject@4:DWORD
extern __ThreadRoutine : PROC

_TEXT SEGMENT

_ThreadRoutine proc
        mov eax,[esp]
        xchg eax,[esp+4]
        mov [esp],eax
        call __ThreadRoutine
        mov ecx,_gDriverObject
        jmp __imp_@ObfDereferenceObject@4
_ThreadRoutine endp

_TEXT ENDS
END
```

with this you can **not wait** fot working thread exit - simply signal to him terminate (`bStopThread = TRUE;`) and return from driver unload.

Comment: @OrielCochavi - handles,pointers to thread independ from running thread or terminated. even after thread terminated it object (`ETHREAD`) will be not destroyed until exist pointers or handles to it. and you sill can query some properties (exit code) of thread after it terminated

Comment: Sorry, I'm writing a long comment and press ENTER by mistake. 

The previous comment:
"**Why does ObReferenceObjectByHandle succeed and not fail? -The thread is long gone.** - my bad, I didn't consider the open handle to the thread."

Comment: **How to determine if thread terminated?** - I can't use KeWaitForSingleObject because I want the driver to keep executing the rest of its logic. But I still want to check if the thread is running (not with technics like keepalive checks or other technics - but by some system check or attribute from the handle or reference, maybe some query using the handle?).

 **Is there a way to check if the thread is terminated prematurely?** - I meant that someone killed the thread, so It didn't reach the part of the code that I can notify myself (with boolean or something) that the thread is dead.

Comment: @OrielCochavi at first you can wait driver unload for thread, if we send command to terminate to him. at second, how i show - we can not wait to thread at all. *But I still want to check if the thread is running* - at first and main - this is senseless. what this give you ? of course you can check this by `PsGetThreadExitStatus` - i in detail explain this point. *prematurely* - again - you ara on wrong way. this is your thread. you control how and when it mast exit

Comment: Just to see if understand it correctly, there is no way that a thread will die (and I don't mean by exception or by my hand) unless I terminate it? there is no way to locate a particular thread and kill it?

Comment: windows not let terminate kernel mode thread from another thread. thread must terminate itself only. so only way terminate your thread external - insert kernel mode apc to it and call `PsTerminateSystemThread` from here. but in this case possible instead terminated, simply infinite wait call..

Comment: so check - are thread running - no big sense. you can do this by call `PsGetThreadExitStatus` or `KeWaitForSingleObject` with `*Timeout = 0`. but this little give you

Comment: about wait for thread terminated from driver unload - you must do this, or use technique with  `jmp __imp_@ObfDereferenceObject@4` - in this case not need wait